# How can I safely open the chest in a Wood Wall Trap?

Tags: dont-starve

I often come across [Wood Wall Traps](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Set_Piece#Wood_Wall_Trap) in my worlds. The fire staff is really powerful early on, and the rest of the resources are nice too, but it's hard to get anything out of the chest without it exploding and burning everything to ash. I got lucky the first time I saw one, when it didn't light anything on fire at all, but I haven't been successful since.

Is there some way to reliably open them safely, or is it just blind luck?

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of ways to deal with the fire trapped chest:

First you can disarm it by grabbing the gun powder out of the chest first. If you take that item out of the chest the trap will no longer trigger. You have to do this pretty quickly for it to be effective.

Second is prevention. The chest is what catches fire. You can prevent it from spreading. Hammer away the nearby wood walls so that they don't catch fire when the trap triggers. You can leave most of them standing, just hammer the ones that are nearest to the chest so the fire can't jump to them. You can always rebuild them later after the fire stops burning.

Answer (score 2):

I opened it safely by just storing some rocks in the chest. I was able to grab everything out of it then.

Answer (score 0):

You actually just have to use a torch on the chest it will burn the chest leaving everything else and the things it has in it don’t burn too

Answer (score -2):

Just hammer the chest and get all the goods.

Answer (score -2):

i had to hammer the pig head first otherwise no matter what i did it would explode

Comment: "pig head" Did autocorrect change something or do you actually mean it?

Comment: Haven't played the game for a long time but sounds... plausable.

Answer (score -5):

Its a 50/50 chance. It'll either burn or it won't.

Comment: Is the chance of opening safely 50%, or do you mean that it sometimes can be opened safely and sometimes can't? Can you somehow back that claim up?